# Error trying to open JSON tweet file

Tags: python, json

I'm getting the following error when attempting to open a json file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 5, in <module>
data = json.load(data_file)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 346, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 8300 column 1 (char 157 - 30292811)
```

This is what I"m doing to open the file in idle:

```
import json

with open('three_minutes_tweets.json','r', encoding="utf-8") as data_file:

data = json.load(data_file)

print(data_file)
```

The file is a tweet sample file and looks likes simple dictionaries of dictionaries. Thank you

Comment: You data is not valid json, if you look at the line mentioned you will see why

Comment: May you flush data_file content before you try to parse it into json format, just for debug purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. There is extra data starting at character 157. In other words, you have invalid JSON data. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I think I found the issue but sure what I should do about it. There is a large space in the file